# How to handle empty body responses in FineUploaderBasic

Tags: fine-uploader

My server returns status code for upload (201) with empty body. I can upload data to server but then onComplete callback is fired i get

```
Error when attempting to parse xhr response text (SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input)
```

FineUploader expects JSON response which i did not provide, is there any way (except manualy modify FinneUploader JS file) to tell FineUploader not to attempt parse response and just check for valid status?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  You will find that relying on status codes will cause you problems in IE9 and older, since a form inside a hidden iframe is submitted for each file in those browsers, and there is no way, via javascript, to determine the response code for such a request.